# Export DataTable to excel in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, export-to-excel

I need to export the `DataTable`. If the `DataColumn` contains "<" means, exported excel  column value will be empty .

I Added :

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Still same result . How can I solve this ?

Comment: Try [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) to get started. It's fairly easy to use.

Comment: Could you show code that exports datatable to excel? Is it openxml or interop?

Comment: Or EPPlus... It actually offers a method to load in DataTables.